# Copy two string on assembly

Tags: string, assembly, copy, masm, irvine32

### this is a code for copying 2 strings

```
TITLE Copying a String (CopyStr.asm)
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
source BYTE "This is the source string",0
target BYTE SIZEOF source DUP(0)
.code
main PROC
mov esi,0 ; index register
mov ecx,SIZEOF source ; loop counter
L1:
mov al,source[esi] ; get a character from source
mov target[esi],al ; store it in the target
inc esi ; move to next character
loop L1 ; repeat for entire string
exit
main ENDP
END main
```

---

mov esi,0 ; index register

why it assumes that the index will start with 0 how did it know that the index of the SOURCE is 0 
i think it should be

```
mov esi , offset Source
```

???

Comment: The code is completely dump, it should be using `rep movsb`...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

```
mov al,source[esi] ; get a character from source
```

`esi` is the "**E**xtended **S**ource **I**ndex" register, which stores the offset in the source (string) (more about the ESI/EDI registers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856320/purpose-of-esi-edi-registers)).

Answer (score 0):

`source` is in the *.data* section, this symbol is the starting address of the string. The **esi** register stores a byte offset starting at the `source` address. The lower part of the **eax** register receives the content of the memory at `source` base address plus the offset inside **esi** (0, 1, 2, 3, ... as the loop goes).