# Why Does This C Code Produce This Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, 32-bit

Quick question about the answer to the question: [Purpose of ESI & EDI registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856320/purpose-of-esi-edi-registers)

```
srcp [srcidx++] = argv [j]; C code translates too

8B550C         mov    edx,[ebp+0C]
8B0C9A         mov    ecx,[edx+4*ebx]
894CBDAC       mov    [ebp+4*edi-54],ecx
47             inc    edi
```

I've taken an assembly class and know the basics, not looking for what `mov` means, but I'm mostly confused as the what the `+0C`, the `+4*ebx`, and the `ebp+4*edi-54` statements are for. He explains it in the post but I'm still not understanding.

The `ebp+12` has `argv`, but why is it incremented by 12?

The `ebx` is `j`, but why is that multiplied by 4 and added onto `ebp`?

And he says that "third instruction uses `edi` multiplied by 4 and adds `ebp` offset by `0x54` (location of `srcp`)"; why does it have to be multiplied by 4? 
Also he says *add the offset*; why is it `-54` and not `+54` in the code?

Just a little confused.

Comment: i think multiplication by 4 exists because the type of argv is a 4 bytes one (int for example).

Comment: exactly your question is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1858322/1632887)

Answer (score 6):

I think we have the following:

- `srcidx` lives in `edi` register
- `argv` is at offset 0xc from the start of the frame (thus `[ebp+0C]`)
- `j` is indeed in `ebx` - the reason we have times 4 is that we are working with an array of 4 byte integers so the offset has to be multiplied by the size of the element (4) to get the correct address.
- `srcp` is a stack variable positioned at offset -54 relative to the start of the frame (`ebp`)

I hope that answers your questions. It might help to load the code in a debugger and run it through stepping one instruction at a time and dumping the registers and portions of memory at each step and comparing it with the state of your variables.

Comment: Yes that helps alot thanks, is there a reason it's -54 to the start of the base? I know variables in the stack are referenced using offsets. So when the brackets are around the entire equation, would it be taking the value of J in ebx and multiplying it by 4, then adding it to edx to store in ecx?

Comment: -54 comes from the layout of the stack. That is just where the array happened to be due to the nature of the code. Brackets mean `dereference the address`, you can think of them as being similar to the * operator on pointers in C.  `mov` arguments here are destination then source, so it is the other way around for `mov    [ebp+4*edi-54],ecx`